# How to control number of threads using by mpsolve library

Tags: c

I recently tried to parallelize my C code using the OpenMP library. It worked until the moment I call the [MPSolve](https://github.com/robol/MPSolve.git) library to find the roots of a polynomial. When the code needs to perform this task it creates multiple threads without my control.

I know that MPsolve uses a multithreading algorithm to increase performance with pthread library, but I would like to know if the number of threads can be controlled when using it because I intend to use this code in a cluster and I would not like to use the limit of available threads.

I expected understand if it is possible to limit the number of threads that mpsolve creates and how to do it

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs that speaks to controlling behavioral details such as the number of threads used.  Possibly one or more of the command line options (`-a`, for example) could cause the program to run in serial mode, but that's not clear to me.

Comment: `-j` option has to be used `-j n        Number of threads to spawn as workers`. According to the source code it does the following:  `s = mps_context_new (); mps_thread_pool_set_concurrency_limit (s, NULL, num_threads);    s->n_threads = num_threads;`

Comment: Thanks for the help. When doing `s->n_threads = num_threads` in my code the following error appears: **dereferencing pointer to incomplete type "struct mps_context"** . For me, this error is always related to a wrong declaration of the structure, but in this case I am not finding it, I am declaring `mps_context *s;` before

Comment: Probably best to ask the authors about using MPSolve in multithreaded code. Note that not only the number of threads spanned can be an issue, but also thread safety.